# Update classNames with addEventListener in useEffect hook

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I'm trying to make a hamburger button menu. When I push the button nothing happens. If I log something in  `toogleHamburger` function I can see it in console but styling does not change. If i do not use eventListener in useEffect it throws `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` error. I want to change styling when I push the button. I'm using module.scss thats why I'm using these classnames.

Nav.js

```
 const Nav = () => {

  useEffect(()=>{
  var navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar")
  var ham = document.querySelector(".ham")

  const toggleHamburger = () => {
    navbar.classList.toggle("showNav")
    ham.classList.toggle("showClose")
}

  ham.addEventListener("click", toggleHamburger)

  var menuLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".menuLink")
  menuLinks.forEach( 
    function(menuLink) { 
      menuLink.addEventListener("click", toggleHamburger) 
      menuLink.removeEventListener("click", toggleHamburger) 
    }
)
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <button className={`${styles.ham} ham`}></button>
      <nav className={`${styles.navbar} navbar`}>
      <ul>
        <li><a className={`${styles.menuLink} menuLink`} href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a className={`${styles.menuLink} menuLink`} href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a className={`${styles.menuLink} menuLink`} href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a className={`${styles.menuLink} menuLink`} href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
  );
};
```

_nav_module.scss

```
.ham {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url("https://ljc-dev.github.io/testing0/ham.svg");
  background-size: 100%;
}

.showClose {
  background-image: url("https://ljc-dev.github.io/testing0/ham-close.svg");
}

.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

.showNav {
  transform: translateY(0);
}


.navbar ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover, .navbar ul li a:focus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid using native DOM methods in React whenever possible - it's usually an antipattern. Attach listeners inside the JSX instead:

```
  return (
    <div>
      <button className={`${styles.ham} ham`} onClick={toggleHamburger}></button>
      <nav className={`${styles.navbar} navbar`}>
      <ul>
        <li><a className={`${styles.menuLink} menuLink`} onClick={toggleHamburger} href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a className={`${styles.menuLink} menuLink`} onClick={toggleHamburger} href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a className={`${styles.menuLink} menuLink`} onClick={toggleHamburger} href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a className={`${styles.menuLink} menuLink`} onClick={toggleHamburger} href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
  );
```

Less repetitively, `.map` the `<li>`s:

```
const Item = ({ menuLink, toggleHamburger, text }) => (
  <li><a className={`${menuLink} menuLink`} onClick={toggleHamburger} href="#">Home</a></li>
);
```

```
  return (
    <div>
      <button className={`${styles.ham} ham`} onClick={toggleHamburger}></button>
      <nav className={`${styles.navbar} navbar`}>
      <ul>
        {
          ['Home', 'Profile', 'About', 'Contact'].map(
            text => <li><a className={`${styles.menuLink} menuLink`} onClick={toggleHamburger} href="#">{text}</a></li>
          )
        }
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: This question must be most stupid thing I have ever asked. I should have think twice when I copy paste a snippet. 
Actually your solution didn't work but it helped me a lot. I found the solution. I should have use CSS instead of module.scss. Thanks btw.